# Dynamically Insert Date into filename of Redshift Copy Command from S3

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am attempting to automate the copy of files from S3 to Redshift. Standing in my way is my ignorance of how to make the date (in bold below) always be today's date.

```
COPY cid_localytics_export
FROM 's3://exports.localytics.t-z/<redacted>/**2014/11/19**/eb0ecf515724b3ef5a6d8cb-a8a0fa68-3551-11e4-4b45-00a426b17dd8/00.log.gz'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<redacted>;aws_secret_access_key=<redacted>' 
JSON 's3://exports.localytics.t-z/<redacted>/redshift_example.json'
GZIP
TRUNCATECOLUMNS;
```

When I attempt the following I get a syntax error. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
COPY cid_localytics_export_test
FROM (select ''''||'s3://exports.localytics.t-z/<redacted>/'||(select ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(cast(date_trunc('day', now()) - interval '1 day' as varchar),'-','/'),' 00:00:00+00',''))))||'/eb0ecf515724b3ef5a6d8cb-a8a0fa68-3551-11e4-4b45-00a426b17dd8/00.log.gz'||'''')
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<redacted>;aws_secret_access_key=<redacted>' 
JSON 's3://exports.localytics.t-z/whitepages/redshift_example.json'
GZIP
TRUNCATECOLUMNS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift copy command expects exact s3 path for folder or file (s3://abc/def or s3://abc/def/ijk.csv )

You need to give correct path for the file.

You can write simple java /php or shell script to ( postgres drivers) create s3 path using date dynamically build query and then fire. So that you replace it with actual date value.

So that there will be on syntax errors.